# can I serve assets from inside of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I would like to package some common assets like css, js, and icon images into a gem for my personal use.

Can I use the assets from inside of the gem directly, or do I have to have a generator move them into the main app?

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is:

- Make a railtie:

  ```
  module MyGemName
    module Rails
      class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- Put them in a directory that would otherwise be a proper asset path, like `lib/assets/stylesheets`.
- Use sprockets to include javascripts:

  ```
  //= require "foobar"
  ```
- Use sass to include stylesheets:

  ```
  @import "foobar";
  ```
- Use the sass function `image-url` if you refer to images inside your stylesheets:

  ```
  .widget {
    background-image: image-url("widget-icon.png");
  }
  ```

The assets directory should behave exactly the same as if it was inside your own application.

You can find an example in [formalize-rails](https://github.com/iain/formalize-rails), which has stylesheets, javascripts and images.

Answer (score 0):

With Rails 3.2 you can create an engine and put the assets in the assets directory where they'll be automatically picked up.  Beware though if you create a mountable engine using the generator, it'll create namespaced directories under javascripts, images, and stylesheets.  Don't put your stuff in those subdirectories or the parent app won't find them.  Just put them directly in javascripts, images, or stylesheets.